# Understanding「それだけの閉じた世界の常識」

Tags: meaning, parsing

A guy was talking about importance of reading books

> 成人男性の脳味噌およそ１４００グラム。
>
> 今となっては、たった**それだけの閉じた世界の常識**、偏った視点のくだす判断に従って生きていくことに、恐怖さえ感じていた。
>
> （もし本を読まなかったら、俺もあんなふうになっちゃうのかなぁ）

I parsed the bold part of sentence like this「(それだけ) の (閉じた (世界の常識))」.

I think それ refers to the mass of brain and だけ means ほど. 閉じた, meaning similar to 狭窄した, modifies the whole 世界の常識 and it means "knowledge about the world which is narrow." Therefore それだけの閉じた世界の常識 means "narrow knowledge about the world which is limited by brain size." Is that right?

For the rest of the sentence, に従って applies to both それだけの閉じた世界の常識 and 偏った視点のくだす判断?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, (たったそれだけの閉じた)世界 is used as a metaphor for one's brain, so 世界の常識 refers to not "the common knowledge about this world" but "the (possibly wrong) knowledge my brain has taken for granted". You may have seen a saying like "Your world is only as wide as what you can see" or something. Every brain has a different and biased idea of what our world is like, so there are many different worlds, so to speak.

> たったそれだけの閉じた世界の常識
> the knowledge such a narrow and enclosed world (=brain) takes for granted

に従って applies to both たったそれだけの閉じた世界の常識 and 偏った視点のくだす判断.

> 今となっては、たったそれだけの閉じた世界の常識、偏った視点のくだす判断に従って生きていくことに、恐怖さえ感じていた。
>
> Now, I even started to find it frightening to live according to the knowledge such a narrow and enclosed "world" has taken for granted, as well as its judgements made from a biased viewpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So たったそれだけの閉じた世界 is parsed like this「(たったそれだけ)の(閉じた世界)」?

Comment: @JimmyYang Yes, the enclosed world which is as small as this.